# jquery parse xml with unlimited child level category

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, recursive-datastructures, parsexml

I'm fairly new on parsing xml with jquery, so if my question looks like noobish, please forgive me.

I have an xml it contains my recursive categories. Some of them has sub categories, some of them not. It has some deep level categories under sub categories.

Sample of xml;

```
<Urunler>
    <Urun>
        <ID>1</ID>
        <Parent>0</Parent>
        <Name>Red</Name>
    </Urun>
    <Urun>
        <ID>2</ID>
        <Parent>0</Parent>
        <Name>Green</Name>
    </Urun>
    <Urun>
        <ID>3</ID>
        <Parent>0</Parent>
        <Name>Blue</Name>
    </Urun>
    <Urun>
        <ID>4</ID>
        <Parent>3</Parent>
        <Name>Sky</Name>
    </Urun>
    <Urun>
        <ID>5</ID>
        <Parent>3</Parent>
        <Name>Sea</Name>
    </Urun>
    <Urun>
        <ID>6</ID>
        <Parent>5</Parent>
        <Name>Fish</Name>
    </Urun>
    <Urun>
        <ID>7</ID>
        <Parent>4</Parent>
        <Name>Bird</Name>
    </Urun>
</Urunler>
```

Desired HTML output

```
<ul>
    <li>Red</li>
    <li>Green</li>
    <li>Blue
        <ul>
            <li>Sky
                <ul>
                    <li>Bird</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Sea
                <ul>
                    <li>Fish</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I find an example on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/43449/parsing-xml-data-to-be-put-onto-a-site-with-jquery
unfortunately it supports only first child level.

if needed;
i call my xml via `$.ajax`

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'webservice/Resim/Kategori.xml',
   dataType: 'xml',
   cache:true,
   success: parseXml
});
```

Any help will greatly appricated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to iterate over the `Urun` elements, and append to the right place in the new UL element

```
function parseXml(xml) {

    var ul = $('<ul />');

    $(xml).find('Urun').each(function(index, item) {
        var parent = parseInt( $(this).find('Parent').text() , 10 );
        var li     = $('<li />', {
            text : $(this).find('Name').text(),
            id   : $(this).find('ID').text()
        });

        if (parent !== 0) {
            var parentEl = ul.find('li#' + parent);

            if ( parentEl.find('ul').length === 0 ) 
                parentEl.append( $('<ul />') );

            parentEl.find('ul').append(li);

        } else {
            ul.append(li);
        }

    });

    $('body').append(ul);

}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/59pbqm46/1/)

Comment: thank you nice solution, but i can not add any html tag into your parse function. As i mentioned in my question i'm newbie on jquery and parsing xml.

Comment: for eg: `<li data-id="4"><a href="some-link">Sky</a><li>`

Comment: Sure you can add that, but in jQuery you do that with `li.append( $('<a />', {href : "some-link"}) )`

Comment: Thank you so much i did it now (: